# Spring Boot certificate configuration in application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I have a .cer (as public key) and a .key file (private key) and I want to use them as a certificate instead of a pfx file. How can I configure this in my application.properties file? Is it possible without using additional transformations of both files? I tried these configurations:

```
server.ssl.certificate-private-key=privatekey.key
server.ssl.certificate=publickey.cer
security.require-ssl=true
```

but I get an IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name ..... HTTP method names must be tokens
```

It simply means, that I try to use HTTPS but did configure HTTP, which should actually not be the case.

I just tried this according the Spring boot documentation in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.server:

```
server.ssl.certificate --> Path to a PEM-encoded SSL certificate file.
server.ssl.certificate--->private-key Path to a PEM-encoded private key file for the SSL certificate.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance